# R shiny How to cancel hover effect in shinyWidgets radioGroupButtons()?

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(
    ".btn-info {background-color: #F0F0F0; color: black; border-color:#F0F0F0; text-align: left;}"),

  radioGroupButtons(
    inputId = "Id067",
    choices = c("Yes (Start the survey)",
                "No (End the survey)"),
    direction = "vertical",
    selected = character(0),
    width   = "100%",
    status = 'info',
    size = 'normal',
))

server = function(...) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to cancel the hover effect in shinyWidgets radioGroupButtons(). When I select an button and then hold down the other option button and then release the mouse after moving out of the button, this causes both buttons to change to blue. I think this question is related to hover or mouseover. Here is the imge of the problem.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a noHover class in your `tags$style` with `pointer-event : none`
as below

```
  tags$style(
    ".btn-info.btn {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: black;
    border-color:#F0F0F0;
    text-align: left;}
    .btn-info.btn:.noHover{
    pointer-events: none;}"
    )
```

below is my screenshot (on click the button becomes blue, no changes on hover )

[image: screen]

Comment: Thank you for the answering. But the selected button doesn't change it's color.

Comment: I test your code with the new ``tags$style`` on click the button becomes blue, I have added a screenshot  in my Answer